# Export variables to pipeline variable

Tags: gitlab, cicd

My cicd file:

```
container_scanning:
      before_script:
        - result=$(cat $NAME.txt)
        - export VERSION="$result"
        - echo $VERSION
      dependencies:
        - pre-build
      variables:
        CS_IMAGE: "<registry>/$BUILD_PATH/$NAME:$VERSION"
        BUILD_PATH: "base_images"
      parallel:
         matrix:
           - NAME: !reference [.base_images]
```

From my runner:

```
[DEBUG] [2023-03-31 06:15:32 +0000] [container-scanning]  >  
trivy image --vuln-type os --no-progress --offline-scan --skip-update --security-checks vuln --format template --template @/usr/local/bundle/gems/gcs-5.3.2/lib/template/trivy.tpl --output tmp.json <registry>/base_images/aws-cli:
```

—

I am facing some issue with using the gitlab template for container scanning

```
include:
  - template: Jobs/Container-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml
```

as shown on my ci file i’ve passed in the version from an artefact from the previous stage. and my echo does shows the correct version that i am getting.
However when i run the scan, on the gitlab runner itself, no version was passed in.

Is there any steps i missed out to pass the variables from before_script?

---

I've tried using this in my `before_script`:

```
- result=$(cat $NAME.txt)
- export VERSION="$result"
- echo VERSION="$result"
- echo "::set-output name=version::$VERSION"
```

And setting this under my variables

```
VERSION: ${{ steps.container_scanning.outputs.version }}
CS_IMAGE: <registry>/$BUILD_PATH/$NAME:$VERSION
```

The end result is see when using `VERSION: ${{ steps.container_scanning.outputs.version }}` during the echo is `}`

Comment: It looks like you're trying to mix syntax for GitHub Actions and GitLab CI. The mechanism of using `echo "::set-output name=version::$VERSION"` and `${{ steps.container_scanning.outputs.version }}` is exclusive to GitHub Actions and is not valid for GitLab CI. Anyhow. It's not quite clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to use this value in another job? Another pipeline? Or the same job, but in the `script:` section or something else? Maybe a more complete version of your CI Yaml will help.

Comment: @sytech I'm trying to run, gitlab container scan which using the `CS_IMAGE` variable declared by them.

The `VERSION` variable need to be passed into the `CS_IMAGE` if not the scan will always take the latest and the report will show error because there is no version.
See the runner logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you clarify what you want to achieve?

I understand that in the `before_script` you set the variable `VERSION`.
Where do you want to use this variable? If you want to use this variable in the `variables` section of the same job then it will not work, because the variables are set before the `before_script` runs.

If this is what you want then you can either

1. set the variable `CS_IMAGE` in the `before_script`
2. another job that will run before this job can publish the value of `VERSION` an .env file

Comment: I'm trying to run, gitlab container scan which using the `CS_IMAGE` variable declared by them.

The `VERSION` variable need to be passed into the `CS_IMAGE` if not the scan will always take the latest and the report will show error because there is no version.
See the runner logs

Comment: Can you add to the question the content of the .gitlab-ci.yml file, or at least the relevant parts or a simplified version of them?